# TPL ETW events have extra parameters that cause excessive debugger output

Tags: .net

Update: this is **not** related to Prefix

I had an earlier version of Prefix installed.  I upgraded by running the new installer.  After upgrading in VS.NET 2015 Update 3, I see these messages in the Debug output window when the Prefix module is loaded.  These messages do not appear when Prefix modules are not loaded.

```
Event 10 was called with 5 argument(s) , but it is defined with 6 paramenter(s).
Event 7 was called with 5 argument(s) , but it is defined with 6 paramenter(s).
```

Is this a problem with Prefix or some other mismatch of components?  Any idea how to fix this?  I get hundreds of these messages while debugging.

**May 3, 2017 Update**: I have been able to determine where these messages are coming from. They are originating in the .NET Framework internal class [System.Threading.Tasks.TPLETWProvider](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TPLETWProvider.cs)  The two events in question are:

Event 7: [TaskScheduled](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TPLETWProvider.cs,cc8b42c4d6a84bfa,references) event method has an extra 6th parameter *int appDomain* that is not used.

Event 10: [TaskWaitBegin](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TPLETWProvider.cs,cf2f546c74097d58,references) which also has an extra unused *int appDomain* parameter.

When each of these methods eventually call EventSource.WriteToAllListeners the parameters on the method are checked against number of data elements passed in. When there is a mismatch, the message appear in the output window in Visual Studio.

The linked sources are are for .NET Framework 4.7.  In my local version, I am running .NET 4.6.1 (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)

I am really surprised more people haven't run into this issue.

Comment: It looks like this might be something deeper as apparently there have been instances of application insights being a possible instigator.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f99be030-a2d9-4013-92f9-075bff0b318a/debugger-output-says-an-event-was-called-with-wrong-number-of-arguments-cant-find-source?forum=vsdebug

Well, we see these same messages in our debuggers as well.  We didn't associate it with Prefix as it was just a message and not an exception of some sort.

Comment: My guess is its related to a setting being applied by both us (and also app insights) that allows us to actually do the profiling work itself.

Comment: Looks like this happens to others in entirely unrelated territory as well.

https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/566

Comment: I noticed the mis-spelling (Paramenters with an extra n) and found this spelling in a resw file associated with Application Insights. So this is possibly the component that detects the issue - don't know if it causes it. 
I also have Prefix running.
The ref to the resw is long and horrible in github....
Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home. see: 

[link](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/Samples/Windows%208.1%20Universal/BlogPostSample/BlogPostSample.Windows/obj/Debug/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource/en-US/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Messages.resw)

Comment: Given that AppInsights now ships pretty much pre-installed with VS 2015/2017 I'm leaning towards that being the culprit of the message very heavily.

Comment: The spelling has to be fixed. as in yesterday!

Comment: Added a issue on the .NET Forums https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ceffc4ed-11a0-497c-bf80-217c8f5af801/some-tpletwprovider-methods-have-too-many-parameters-causes-excessive-debug-output?forum=clr

Comment: I have also opened a Microsoft Connect ticket: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3133569/some-system-threading-tasks-tpleventsource-methods-have-too-many-method-parameters-cause-debug-warnings

Comment: how does one fix this issue?

Comment: @TWilly you as a user of the .NET Framework can not fix this error.  The error is in the .NET Framework source code.

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled across this in my own attempts to discover the cause.

Although **Stackify Prefix** was disabled via the Tray icon, I was still getting these program output messages in the **Output** window.

The solution was to comment out the following line in web.config:

```
<add name="StackifyModule_Net40" type="StackifyHttpTracer.StackifyHttpModule,StackifyHttpTracer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93c44ce23f2048dd" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

Environment: Visual Studio 2019 16.5.1, Stackify Prefix 3.0.28.0 (from stackify.ini)