# Filter custom message from Visual Studio 2015 output window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

At some point in the last couple of months, a lot of message along the lines of

```
Event 7 was called with 5 argument(s) , but it is defined with 6 paramenter(s).
Event 10 was called with 5 argument(s) , but it is defined with 6 paramenter(s).
Event 10 was called with 5 argument(s) , but it is defined with 6 paramenter(s).
```

started spamming my Visual Studio output window making it hard to find actual trace and debug messages.  Where are these messages coming from, and how do I disable them?

To try to solve this problem, I have tried several things.

- Most of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720599/disable-noise-messages-in-debug-output-windows-visual-studio-2012) point to configuring the checkboxes in the output window.  If I uncheck "Program Output" the problem messages go away, but so do the messages I want to keep.
- I tried creating a custom `TraceListener` and set a breakpoint in the `Write` and `WriteLine` methods in the hopes that the call stack would tell me where the messages were being generated from.  I discovered that these messages are not coming from the typical `Diagnotics.Debug` or `Diagnotics.Trace` methods.
- I tried redirecting the console via `Console.SetOut()` to a custom `TextWriter` that I could set breakpoints within.  Again, I could not find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For which projects? [Stackify](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42123222/1997232) ? [Azure](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f99be030-a2d9-4013-92f9-075bff0b318a/debugger-output-says-an-event-was-called-with-wrong-number-of-arguments-cant-find-source?forum=vsdebug) ? [Rebus](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/566) ?

Comment: I am using Stackify Prefix.  Good catch on that one.  I'm not sure how my searching didn't find it.  If you wrap that up as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: You can just delete the question. The answer "It's not you, it's `Stackify`" is unlikely to be useful to others. It's very likely they will find that question too.

Comment: For my own knowledge, what search did you use to find the question?  Variations of "Event 7 was called with 5 argument(s) , but it is defined with 6 parameters)" in Google or "Visual Studio output window" didn't get me to that result in the first few pages.

Comment: @erdomke Did you find where this was coming from and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [@Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr) helpfully mentioned in his comment, this can be caused by several different system configurations which I did not find information on during my initial search.  In particular, more information can be found at the following links:

- [Stackify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42123222/1997232)
- [Azure](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f99be030-a2d9-4013-92f9-075bff0b318a/debugger-output-says-an-event-was-called-with-wrong-number-of-arguments-cant-find-source?forum=vsdebug)
- [Rebus](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/566)

In my situation, the culprit appears to be the combination of Application Insights and Stackify Prefix as documented in the [StackOverflow question linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42123222/1997232).

Answer (score 5):

Ive found the assembly this string is coming from, but not yet how or where.

It is found in mscorlib.dll line 54673 in the raw dll (32 bit version): Event {0} was called with {1} argument(s) , but it is defined with {2} paramenter(s)

Its from the resource name value pairs, this one is named EventSource_EventParametersMismatch

This is being used from system\diagnostics\eventing\eventsource.cs 
WriteToAllListeners
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/eventing/eventsource.cs,7c04b58f26d81951