# Workaround for excessive debug output "Event X was called with Y arguments, but it is defined with Z parameter(s)"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Examples in the debug window in VS2017 (but appearantly also in other VS versions):

```
Event 7 was called with 5 argument(s) , but it is defined with 6 paramenter(s).
```

Finding the cause:
[TPL ETW events have extra parameters that cause excessive debugger output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123222/tpl-etw-events-have-extra-parameters-that-cause-excessive-debugger-output)
[Filter custom message from Visual Studio 2015 output window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814394/filter-custom-message-from-visual-studio-2015-output-window)

But until an update or similar fixes this - any suggestions for **workarounds**? 
(code / tools / ???)

I really want to keep my debug output window working, and not flodded with the same (useless) message.

Disabling certain types of messages in the output window does no good, since it removed the output messages I want.
([Disable noise messages in debug output windows - visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720599/disable-noise-messages-in-debug-output-windows-visual-studio-2012))

Have also tried to find a VS extension that could filter, but no luck.

Down this lane, VSColorOutput can probably used to match by a RegExp, and then change the color of these message to same color as backround in the output window... but that feels really nasty,
and would give endless blank lines in the outputwindow.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest dot net framework installed. They have fixed this now.

See the merged PR here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/8942